# CombineFileInputFormat implementation for XML files

Tags: java, xml, hadoop, mapreduce

I have to process 250 XML files each of which is 25 MB in size. For processing XML files, I am using XMLInputFormat from Apache Mahout and generating a sequence file. The key is filename and value is entire file contents in sequence file. But problem with this approach is that 250 Mappers are launched which makes the MapReduce job slower.

I have come across CombineFileInputFormat (while going through Tom White book) using which 250 Mappers wouldn't be launched for 250 files. But CombineFileInputFormat is an abstract class and I am facing difficulty implementing it for XML files as I am new to Java as well as Hadoop.

So, can someone please provide me implementation of CombineFileInputFormat for XML files.

**Driver Code:**

```
package com.ericsson.sequencefile;
//A MapReduce program for packaging a collection of small files as a single SequenceFile.
//hadoop jar sequencefiles.jar com.ericsson.sequencefile.SmallFilesToSequenceFileConverter -D xmlinput.start="<XMLstart>" -D xmlinput.end="</XMLstart>" /IRIS_NG/pfinder2/ccn/archive /IRIS_NG/pfinder2/output

import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.SequenceFileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

public class SmallFilesToSequenceFileConverter extends Configured implements Tool {

    public static class SequenceFileMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

    private Text filenameKey;

    @Override
    public void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
         InputSplit split = context.getInputSplit();
         Path path = ((FileSplit) split).getPath();
         filenameKey = new Text(path.toString() + "\n");
    }

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
          String document = value.toString();
          context.write(filenameKey, new Text(document));
    }
   }

  @Override
  public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

    if (args.length != 2) {
              System.err.printf("Usage: %s [generic options] <input> <output>\n", getClass().getSimpleName());
              ToolRunner.printGenericCommandUsage(System.err);
              return -1;
     }

    Configuration conf = getConf();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf,"SmallFilesToSequenceFile");
    job.setJarByClass(getClass());
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    job.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);
    job.setInputFormatClass(XmlInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapperClass(SequenceFileMapper.class);

    return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new SmallFilesToSequenceFileConverter(), args);
    System.exit(exitCode);
  }
}
```

**XMLInputFormt.java**

```
package com.ericsson.sequencefile;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.*;
import org.slf4j.*;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Reads records that are delimited by a specific begin/end tag.
 */
public class XmlInputFormat extends TextInputFormat {

  private static final Logger log =
      LoggerFactory.getLogger(XmlInputFormat.class);

  public static final String START_TAG_KEY = "xmlinput.start";
  public static final String END_TAG_KEY = "xmlinput.end";

  @Override
  public RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> createRecordReader(
      InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context) {
    try {
      return new XmlRecordReader((FileSplit) split,
          context.getConfiguration());
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      log.warn("Error while creating XmlRecordReader", ioe);
      return null;
    }
  }

  /**
   * XMLRecordReader class to read through a given xml document to
   * output xml blocks as records as specified
   * by the start tag and end tag
   */
  public static class XmlRecordReader
      extends RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> {

    private final byte[] startTag;
    private final byte[] endTag;
    private final long start;
    private final long end;
    private final FSDataInputStream fsin;
    private final DataOutputBuffer buffer = new DataOutputBuffer();
    private LongWritable currentKey;
    private Text currentValue;

    public XmlRecordReader(FileSplit split, Configuration conf)
        throws IOException {
      startTag = conf.get(START_TAG_KEY).getBytes("UTF-8");
      endTag = conf.get(END_TAG_KEY).getBytes("UTF-8");

      // open the file and seek to the start of the split
      start = split.getStart();
      end = start + split.getLength();
      Path file = split.getPath();
      FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(conf);
      fsin = fs.open(split.getPath());
      fsin.seek(start);
    }

    private boolean next(LongWritable key, Text value)
        throws IOException {
      if (fsin.getPos() < end && readUntilMatch(startTag, false)) {
        try {
          buffer.write(startTag);
          if (readUntilMatch(endTag, true)) {
            key.set(fsin.getPos());
            value.set(buffer.getData(), 0, buffer.getLength());
            return true;
          }
        } finally {
          buffer.reset();
        }
      }
      return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
      fsin.close();
    }

    @Override
    public float getProgress() throws IOException {
      return (fsin.getPos() - start) / (float) (end - start);
    }

    private boolean readUntilMatch(byte[] match, boolean withinBlock)
        throws IOException {
      int i = 0;
      while (true) {
        int b = fsin.read();
        // end of file:
        if (b == -1) {
          return false;
        }
        // save to buffer:
        if (withinBlock) {
          buffer.write(b);
        }

        // check if we're matching:
        if (b == match[i]) {
          i++;
          if (i >= match.length) {
            return true;
          }
        } else {
          i = 0;
        }
        // see if we've passed the stop point:
        if (!withinBlock && i == 0 && fsin.getPos() >= end) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }

    @Override
    public LongWritable getCurrentKey()
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      return currentKey;
    }

    @Override
    public Text getCurrentValue()
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      return currentValue;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(InputSplit split,
                           TaskAttemptContext context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean nextKeyValue()
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      currentKey = new LongWritable();
      currentValue = new Text();
      return next(currentKey, currentValue);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should post what source code you have with the problem you're having with it.

Comment: I assume, the number of mappers depend on your `hdfs-block` size. Are your xml files with different structure and different tag names? In Mahout XML Inputformat you have to specify your xml tagnames; if they are with same structure, can you dump all the xml files in one folder and set up your MR job to scan this folder.

Comment: @ruben123 , In  my case, file size is 25 MB and hdfs block size is 256 MB. So, number of mappers launched is equal to number of XML files. So, if there are 250 files, then 250 mappers are launched.